# react keeping state of render props wrapped components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created the following render props component, through the `children` prop as function:

```
export class GenericAbstractLoader extends React.Component<IGenericAbstractLoaderRenderProps, any> {
    constructor(props: IGenericAbstractLoaderRenderProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    public render() {
        return this.props.isLoading ? (
            <div className="generic-abstract-loader-wrapper">
                <div className="generic-abstract-loader">
                    <img src={loader} />
                </div>
                {this.props.children(this.props)}
            </div>
        ) : (
            this.props.children(this.props)
        );
    }
}
```

It actually just renders the wrapped component if `isLoading` is false, or adds a layer of loading if the prop is true.
It works "quite perfectly".

I do call it in this way from another component:

```
public render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.justDisable}>JUST SET FALSE TO STATE</button>
            <br />
            <button onClick={this.enableDisable}>Disable/Enable Elements</button>
            <br />

            <GenericAbstractLoader customProp="custom prop" isLoading={this.state.shouldDisable}>
                {props => <HomeTestForm {...props} />}
            </GenericAbstractLoader>
        </div>
    );
}
```

As you can see the wrapped component is a simple `HomeTestForm` which contains just one input text:

```
export class HomeTestForm extends React.Component<IGenericAbstractLoaderHOCProps, any> {
    constructor(props: IGenericAbstractLoaderHOCProps) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.state = { value: 'Initial Value' };
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }

    public handleChange(event: any) {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    }
}
```

My issue is that when I toggle the `isLoading` prop, the state isn't kept by the wrapped component, so if I change the value of the inner text field, when adding the loading layer, and when removing it, the value is not taken, so the input field is still rendered with the init value.

What's the right way to create persistent wrapped components with render props?

Comment: I am not talking about application state, but simple component state. 
I don't want to use redux for that. 
I simply need a way to store the current state of the wrapped component passed in (the `this.state` let's say to understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component's state is getting reset because React is creating an entirely new component when your loading state changes. You can see these if you add a `console.log` to the constructor of `HomeTestForm`. React thinks this is necessary because of the ternary operator in `GenericAbstractLoader`. If you can restructure the `render` function in `GenericAbstractLoader` to something like the example below, you can give React the context it needs to persist the component instance across renders.

```
render() 
  return (
    <div className={this.props.isLoading ? "generic-abstract-loader-wrapper" : ""}>
      {this.props.isLoading && <img src={loader} />}
      {this.props.children(this.props)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

React's documentation has a brief section about this under [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#elements-of-different-types). This situation falls under the Elements of Different Types heading.

Also, unrelated to your question, based on your current example you don't need to use a render prop. The `render` function in `GenericAbstractLoader` can just render `{this.props.children}` without the function call and you can place your props directly on the child component as in the example below. You may have just simplified your example for SO and have a situation where you need render props, but I wanted to point this out just in case.

```
<GenericAbstractLoader isLoading={this.state.shouldDisable}>
  <HomeTestForm customProp="custom prop" />
</GenericAbstractLoader
```